# Why can't I set %USERPROFILE% for downloads in my C# project?

Tags: windows, c#, wildcard, visual-studio-2017

I am working on a program that retrieves files for the user from the internet. When I set the download path, either nothing happens, or Visual Studio tells me my path cannot be written to. Here are paths that I have tried:

```
(@"%USERNAME%\Downloads\");
(@"%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\");
(@"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Downloads\");
(@"C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\");
```

What's even stranger is that using `(@"%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\");` puts the downloaded files to the same folder as the program folder within a folder called `%USERPROFILE%`. I have used `%USERPROFILE%` in batch scripting before with no issues, is it a different wildcard in C#? What am I missing here?

Comment: A programmer has to do this himself, use Environment.GetFolderPath().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# does not automatically expand environment variables from strings.  Doing so could have serious security implications among other issues.

You need to use the `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables` method before attempting the file operation, for example something like;

```
using system;

void Main()
{  
    String DownloadPath= @"%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\";

    String ExpandedDownloadPath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(DownloadPath);
    Console.WriteLine("ExpandedPath: {0}", ExpandedDownloadPath);
}
```

Obviously this is more a StackOverflow (programming) question

Answer (score 1):

%Variablename% is batch syntax. In c# you have to resolve the environment variables manually.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/77zkk0b6(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
String DownloadPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + "\\Downloads";
```